# When using XCode "Source Repository->Update…", why is my current iOS device always reverted to "My Mac-64 bit"?

Tags: xcode

It's an annoyance-level thing only, as the remedy is to quit/restart Xcode and all my shared schemes seem to come back just fine. But immediately after an update (we use svn for now), if there were updates to the project.pbxproj file, the currently selected device gets replaced with "Mac 64-bit" (which is completely unrunnable, of course for an iOS project). What gives?

Comment: I've had the same thing for the last while. I think it's a UI bug in XCode.

Comment: No need to restart. Edit scheme and reselect .app in the dropdown.

Comment: Alas @Saran, that does not work. Edit scheme shows the same stuff mangled. Still have to restart Xcode - but thank you for the suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: Click edit scheme, on the dialog on the right box under info tab in the dropdown next to Executable, click and reselect the .app, It works for me.

Comment: Thanks - you're right; I was being dense. Appreciated.

Comment: @Saran - please repost as answer; while the issue is (IMHO) an Xcode bug, your  suggestion allows avoiding restarts which is worth being the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On Xcode, next to run,stop click project and Click edit scheme
2. On the dialog on the right box info tab will be
   default selection, if not select it.
3. On the dropdown next to
   executable, click and reselect the .app